# Are the Sisters of Silence Augmented Humans?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In the Master of Mankind the Silent Sisters are shown as being almost the equal to Custodes in terms of fighting ability and Survivability however I have not read anything that suggests the Sisters have undergone the kind of Augmentation that Custodes, Astartes etc undergo.

Has it been detailed anywhere the kind of initiation that sisters undergo, are they augmented and changed to make them stronger, more resilient, longer lived etc?

Comment: I might like to add, if you like custodians and sisters of the Anathema Pskyana. I would strongly recommend the novel "Watchers of the throne: the emperor's legion" its mostly through the 1st person perspective of custodian and sitser, it is set in the current time line.

Answer (score 2):

What is your source that they are almost equal of Custodes?
I am genuinely curious because I would say even a Space Marine would easily win against a regular Sister of Silence.
They are of course really effective against Pyskers though.
They are always deployed either against Psykers (*Burning of Prospero*) or Deamons.
As far as I know they are not augmented and are only stronger because of their power armour which increases the wielders strength considerably.
Their training is really intense and they are probably the top of baseline human female physique. Adding to the fact that they are all nulls which unsettles even normal humans and is extremely torturing for a Psyker to be around, I would wager that also makes them slightly more effective than usual even against non Psykers.

There are a couple highly skilled individuals within the Sisters of Silence though, but that goes for all Imperial organisations and should not be taken as the baseline for comparison. (A Lucifer Black was skilled enough to wound Alpharius in solo combat, Lucifer Black's are normal humans without modification).

Primarch > Custodes > Asartes > Sisters > rest of the Imperial military.

Comment: In Master of Mankind they are shown fighting alongside the Custodes going toe to toe with the forces of Chaos with the same levels of physical resilience, the same combat ability (in one scene a sister is shown fighting alongside a Custode as his equal in terms of combat ability) in terms of game rules Sisters of Silence have a better stat line then an average space marine as well.

Comment: @RichardC A custodes would mop the floor with a sister quite easely. but that isn't a fair fight. Custodes and Sisters fight very well together as they where meant to fight that way. but 1v1 they stad absolutely no chance. and they where fighting warp entities or being empowered by the warp, they are specifically strong against that

Comment: No Warp entities are weak against the sisters, a sisters strength and stamina remain constant and the fact a sister can fight for days on end with no rest, can survive injuries that would kill any normal human and can kill traitor Astartes in hand to hand combat suggests that they must be enhanced in some way.

Comment: The sister you mention in the specific instance was Jenetia Krole, the leader of the sisters of silence and one of the most renowned warriors of the imperium, she is indeed capable of going toe to toe with a custodes, her null presence is so powerful that the custodes cant even read her hand sings clearly. but again she is not the baseline and an extraordinary individual., she would mop the floor with any of her sisters.